# Masking of credit card nos and showing it to correct logged in person is not showing

Tags: javascript, regex, security, dynamics-crm, customization

I have written a simple javascript function which which will mask all credit card nos digits except the last four digits for agent login and for any other login(admin/manager) it will display all the credit card
digits(12) without masking.

I am facing two issues here: one - it is masking for everyone irrespective of agent or manager login. Another one: the masking is such that the last four digits shows at front and the remaining is shown a complete blank space, for better understanding I am providing both code and screenshot of the masking.

```js
// JavaScript source code
function RetrieveLoggedInD365UserSecurityRoles(executionContext) {

var roleName = "Agent";
//will retrieve the credit Card Number from the form
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var creditCardNum = formContext.getAttribute("cts_creditcardnumber").getValue();
var duplicatecreditCardNum = creditCardNum;
//
//to retrive the global user context from the d365 security profile
var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
var userRoles = globalContext.userSettings.roles;

//using regex it will mask the digits of credit card Numbers
userRoles.forEach(function hasRoleName(item) {
if (item.name == roleName) {
alert("i m in!!")
var replacedCreditCardNum = creditCardNum.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "x");
formContext.getAttribute("cts_creditcardnumber").setValue(replacedCreditCardNum);
};
if (item.name != rolename) {
formContext.getAttribute("cts_creditcardnumber").setValue(duplicatecreditCardNum);
};

}
);

}
```

It should have shown as "xxxxx-xxxx-0123" and its masking for all logins irrespective of agent or administrator

[image]

Comment: you can't store a credit card number in plain text, because any user with access to that field can see the value from advanced find, because the JS to mask the number will not be executed there. I will not comment on the other several reasons why storing a credit card number in plain text is wrong.

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a flaw - both `if` statements will execute on every role and switch the masking, thats why the behavior is confusing you.

You should have a flag and default it to false, then iterate and check - only when the necessary role is returned in the user roles list - you should set the flag as true.

Then based on flag, you should mask/unmask it.

(Though this should have been done in server side itself as the field level security cannot be done for partial masking and not on client side as a best practice to avoid exposed in client side code, Maybe retrieve/retrieve multiple plugin is an option at the cost of performance impact)

```
var userHasAccess = false;

userRoles.forEach(function hasRoleName(item) {
    if (item.name == roleName) {
        alert("I'm in!!")
        userHasAccess = true;
    };
});

if(userHasAccess == false){
    var replacedCreditCardNum = creditCardNum.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "x");
    formContext.getAttribute("cts_creditcardnumber").setValue(replacedCreditCardNum);
}
else{
    formContext.getAttribute("cts_creditcardnumber").setValue(duplicatecreditCardNum);
}
```

For regex us some [online tester](https://regex101.com/) to see it in action.

Comment: sorry to be so naive I should have researched a bit then should post this question although it seems my script is working fine in respect of the roles, the only thing I needed is to deploy the web resources properly, although coming to my second query I tried regex tester for my masking and it was working fine yet dynamics is not supporting the 'x' characters before my last four credits and it is still displaying like the image I have posted above .

Comment: Coming to security part, you are correct, even I raised the same flag, although requirements were something else, it could be easily deployable by a plugin for security purpose

Comment: @subhajitseal you should be able to debug in browser dev toolbar (F12) to troubleshoot.. did you try? Also we don’t want to set the value in the database but just a presentation - so you should try web resource or pcf control.. or simply keep two attributes - one for admin and one for agent (masked in db itself) - and to hide/show based on form/control